# Swap columns using sed linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, text-files

My task is to swap second and fourth column in a file using `sed`:

```
Filesystem  Size    Used   Avail   Use% Mounted on
rootfs         583G  380G   203G  66%   /
devtmpfs    1.9G   252K   1.9G   1%     /dev
tmpfs         2.0G    2.5M   1.9G   1%     /dev/shm
/dev/sda1  583G   380G  203G  66%   /
```

my `sed` script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/\(.*\)\s\+\(.*\)\s\+\(.*\)\s\+\(.*\)\s\+\(.*\)\s\+\(.*\)/\1 \3 \4 \2 \5 \6/g
```

This does not work and I cannot figure out why. Can anyone please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I edited my sed script to:     `s/\(.*\)\s\s*\(.*\)\s\s*\(.*\)\s\s*\(.*\)\s\s*\(.*\)\s\s*\(.*\)\n$/\1\4\3\2\5\6/g` and it still doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/^(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)/\1\4\3\2/' ip.txt 
Filesystem  Avail   Used   Size    Use% Mounted on
rootfs         203G  380G   583G  66%   /
devtmpfs    1.9G   252K   1.9G   1%     /dev
tmpfs         1.9G   2.5M   2.0G    1%     /dev/shm
/dev/sda1  203G  380G  583G   66%   /
```

- `-E` use ERE, some `sed` versions need `-r` option instead
- `^` start of line anchor
- `(\S+\s+)` defines one column - non-whitespace characters followed by whitespace characters

  - use it four times to get first four columns
  - then in replacement section, re-arrange in whatever order is required

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but do you have any idea why my regex wouldn't work on this one? :)

Comment: `*` is a greedy quantifier, it will try to match as much as possible while trying to match whole expression as well... in this case, the first `.*` you used matched too much to be useful as there are multiple spaces and `\s+` is matching just one space for later expressions... for ex: try `sed -E 's/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/\1/' ip.txt` on your file..

Comment: you can also see this particular regex in action on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V0D8ih/1).... see also https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics

Comment: and why don't I have to put \ in front of every ( and ) for this to work? I got an error saying "invalid reference" everytime I used parenthesis before.

Comment: by default, sed uses BRE where you need to escape the `()`... but I used the `-E` option to tell sed to use ERE where you don't need to escape them... see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html

Comment: I have just one more question... so `sed` works line by line?